# python - transform a C# method in python method

Tags: python, django, xml, zeep

I'm new in Python and I trying to make this C# method

```
protected void read(){
string[] attributes = new string[16];
        attributes[0] = "ref_num";
        attributes[1] = "tenant.name";
        attributes[2] = "request_by.first_name";
        attributes[3] = "request_by.first_name";
        attributes[4] = "customer.first_name";
        attributes[5] = "customer.last_name";
        attributes[6] = "customer.id";
        attributes[7] = "category.sym";
        attributes[8] = "status.sym";
        attributes[9] = "group.last_name";
        attributes[10] = "zreporting_met.sym";
        attributes[11] = "assignee.combo_name";
        attributes[12] = "open_date";
        attributes[13] = "close_date";
        attributes[14] = "description";
        attributes[15] = "summary";
        int sid = soap.login("user", "pass");
        string objectType = "cr";
        string whereClause = "ref_num = '15967'";
        int maxRows = -1;
        //Valor de tiempo en Epoch
        var epoch = (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalSeconds;
        //Transforma en valor de fecha humana
        string _epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddSeconds(epoch).ToShortDateString();
        ArrayList resultado = new ArrayList();
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        try
        {
            string _selectResponse = soap.doSelect(sid, objectType, whereClause, maxRows, attributes);
            xml.LoadXml(_selectResponse);
            XmlNodeList nodeList = xml.GetElementsByTagName("AttrValue");
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.Count; i++)
            {
                resultado.Add(nodeList[i].InnerXml);
            }
            soap.logout(sid);
        }
        catch (Exception l)
        {
            Console.Write(l.Message);
        }
}
```

this method works perfectly, in python I have this for the moment

```
class WebService:

soap = 'webservice url'

client = Client(soap)

sid = client.service.login("user","pass")
attributes = ["ref_num", "open_date"]
objectType = "cr"
whereClause = "open_date > 1519862400 AND open_date &lt; 1522368000"
maxRows = -1
tickets = client.service.doSelect(sid, objectType, whereClause, -1, attributes)
print(tickets)
logout = client.service.logout(p)
```

using zeep to connect to the Web Service

the error what I have is in attributes array, the login method, works but when I try to use `doSelect()` method it says:

```
zeep.exceptions.ValidationError: Missing element string (doSelect.attributes)
```

Someone can help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include the full traceback. But also, Python doesn't _force_ you to create any classes of your own. `class WebService:` seems completely redundant in relation to the rest of your code. Also, your indentation is wonky, please fix that.

Comment: Please format your python code and provide workable example in python. Where does `Client` class come from?

Comment: Client class comes from zeep lib EvgenyPogrebnyak, and roganjosh the code has no error... the only error is in zeep when I call the WebService method